# Error: "Code generation for property 'ContentControl' failed." (C#)

Tags: c#, resources

I added some images to my resources. Then, I decided not to use them and removed them from **Resources.rex** and **Resources folder**. Now, I am getting this error when I try to run the application:

[image]

Comment: have you tried a clean and build?  just in case...

Comment: Yes, I have tried cleaning and building but It didn't work. I can't even save the project because of this error!

Comment: Well if you can do a build(not run), at least 99% of your project is saved if not everything.  Try reopening it.  Also go take a look at the Resources.Designer.cs and see if there is a reference in there.  it will put it in the global::Namespace.blah.blah.*, if it's there, remove the reference.  Something to try.

Answer (score 0):

Please try unload project then load project again , then clean solution and rebuild again, hope it will solve problem